# CreateFile in C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am using `CreateFile` function to create HID Device Handle. Below is sample code. After executing the code, I am always getting HidHandle value `-1`, which it should not be. Any suggestions please.

```
public int CreateFile(string FileName)
{
    HidHandle = CreateFile(FileName,GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);           
}

 [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern int CreateFile(
        string lpFileName,                          
        uint dwDesiredAccess,                       
        uint dwShareMode,                           
        uint lpSecurityAttributes,              
        uint dwCreationDisposition,                 
        uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,                  
        uint hTemplateFile                          
        );
```

Calling `GetLastWin32Error()` returns the value `5`.

Comment: Have you tried calling GetLastError to obtain any more detailed error information?

Comment: The [page at pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.createfile) has a slightly different sig and a sample to get more info.

Comment: Hello David, Thanks for reply.Is "GetLastError" is allowed to use in C#.Is there any equivalent of it.Let me know,

Comment: Hello Henk, I didn't Got u.Could be more specific. Thanks

Comment: Sure, you can just write a declaration for it as you did CreateFile
[DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern Int32 GetLastError();

Comment: I have defined in following way. I am getting Error Status =5. What does this mean an how shd I understand it. Thanks,                    " ErrorStatus = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();"  [DllImport("ws2_32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Int32 WSAGetLastError();

Comment: What are you passing in `filename`? I was try to get some values directly from `c:` with this WinAPI. I got it but only runed as administrator..

Comment: I am using CreateFile function to create HID Device Handle. This device handle is indeed passed to WriteFile Function.Coming to CreateFile function I am passing USB device Path coming from "PSP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DETAIL_DATA" function.

Comment: Hello Sharper, Could you send me your code.I will try myself.Thanks\

Answer (score 4):

`CreateFile` is returning `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE` which indicates failure. You then call  `GetLastWin32Error()` which returns 5. This is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. In other words, your process does not have sufficient rights to open that file.

Answer (score 1):

try changing that to

```
public int CreateFile(string FileName)
{
  return CreateFile(FileName,GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
       FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,0,OPEN_EXISTING,0,0);           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CreateFile is not an exported function from kernel32.dll
kernel32.dll exports either CreateFileW or CreateFileA

You should use

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int CreateFileW(
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string lpFileName,
uint dwDesiredAccess,
uint dwShareMode,
IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes,
uint dwCreationDisposition,
uint dwFlagsAndAttributes,
IntPtr hTemplateFile
);

Comment: If [ExactSpelling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.exactspelling) is not set to true, the entry points with appended A/W are also found according to the specified [CharSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.charset)

Comment: Yes. I known But is better and easier to debug if you don't assume and use the exact form by yourself..
in my opinion.

Comment: Is `int` instead of `IntPtr` correct, though? For the return value, I mean.